# PHP regex - for [[_string_]], return _string_?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Developing a shorthand parser as part of a client's application. I want to set up a shorthand for creating links similar to mediawiki.

I.E.: `[[link_location|link_title]]` eventually becomes `<a href="link_location">link_title</a>`

What I need to do is extract the string from between the brackets so I can process it; there's a bunch of validation and keyword conversion to do before it can go into a link. I'm pretty new to `preg_match` - I can match the bracketed expression with `/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/`, but I have no idea how to extract the string from the middle. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? Or, if I'm going about this all wrong, have mercy and point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I should have clarified: I need to extract the string and process it, so `preg_replace`ing it directly into a link won't work in this case.

Comment: Is there a reason you create your own syntax instead of using [bbcode & the library for that](http://www.php.net/bbcode)?

Comment: Yeah - this is all client-specified, and meant to behave more like a wiki than anything else. They want to develop a small number of shorthand expressions like `**` for `<strong>` and `-----` for `<hr>`

Comment: Ah well, in that case (although you may find generic libs which can be configured I wouldn't know one OTOH), go for the `preg_replace_callback()` option, you can do anything you want with any subpattern you like in the replace.

Comment: It would be great if you could **tell the client that coming up with yet another ever-so-slightly-different syntax is a stupid idea**, and they should pick one of the many existing ones (e.g. bbcode, creole, markdown, textile, [etc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_markup_language)) that people already know and which have existing robust libraries for dealing with, and thus wont result in you wasting time re-inventing something and having to fix annoying issues that others have already encountered and solved.

Comment: ^ And yes, Peter has a point. Don't convince them with technical details, convince them with how many extra hours will be billed versus near 'out-of-the-box' behavior... that may do the trick ;)

Comment: Hahaha, you guys rock. We all like to gripe about stupid client decisions and pretend like we have control over the path of our projects - but if they're ignorant enough to make a decision like re-inventing shorthand, then they're impulsive enough to take the work somewhere else if I push back. I'd rather just grit my teeth, get paid, and let them have their crappy product ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$string = preg_replace("/\[\[([^\|]+)|([^\]]+)\]\]/", "<a href=\"\\1\">\\2</a>", $string);
```

more

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

p.s. not tested.

---

as for edit:

```
preg_match("/\[\[([^\|]+)\|([^\]]+)\]\]/", $input, $m);

$m[1] -- now is the location
$m[2] -- now is the title
```

and if you have many:

```
preg_match_all("/\[\[([^\|]+)\|([^\]]+)\]\]/", $input, $m);

$m[1] -- now contains all location occurrences
$m[2] -- now contains all title occurrences
```

[edit] fixed bugs.

Comment: Sorry, I was ambiguous - this doesn't solve my problem. Please read my edits.

Comment: I was able to piece together a solution from parts of your answer, but some of it isn't right ;)

Answer (score 2):

`$1` gets the first matched group, `$2` gets the second etc.

Here's working code for your case:

```
preg_replace("/\[\[(.*?)\|(.*?)\]\]/", "<a href=\"$1\">$2</a>", "[[link_location|link_title]]");
```

Comment: Sorry, I was ambiguous - this doesn't solve my problem. Please read my edits.